# How to Convert coordinates to address using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, geocoding, xcode10

I try to use `reverseGeocoordinate` to show the address from `locationEnd` at my `DestinationSearchBar` but i don't know how to do it.

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 15.0)

   if locationSelected == .startLocation {
        addressSearchBar.text = "\(place.coordinate.latitude), \(place.coordinate.longitude)"
        locationStart = CLLocation(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
        createMarker(titleMarker: "Punto de recojo", iconMarker: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "marker"), latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
    } else {
        DestinationSearchBar.text = "\(place.coordinate.latitude), \(place.coordinate.longitude)"
        locationEnd = CLLocation(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
        createMarker(titleMarker: "Punto de destino", iconMarker: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "marker"), latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)



    self.mapView.camera = camera
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly is not working? If there's errors, please post the error message. If not, the expected result and the actual result you're getting makes it easier to answer your question.

Comment: I am going to change the way in which I pose my question, basically what I want to know is "how to do it", my mistake.

Answer (score 10):

Apple providing reverse geo location api

```
let address = CLGeocoder.init()
    address.reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation.init(latitude: latitude, longitude:longitude)) { (places, error) in
        if error == nil{
            if let place = places{
                //here you can get all the info by combining that you can make address
            }
        }
    }
```

and don't forget imports

```
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
```

Comment: yes @MiguelJesusEcheniqueMachado it will work if you are giving it cordinates it does not matter from which api you are getting cordinates